# Liferay AssetEntryQuery filter by asset type (Jython)

Tags: python, liferay, jython, portlet

Trying to get a list of assets filtered by category AND asset type (e.g. blog). I have the AssetEntryQuery working in a python portlet:

```
from com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.persistence import AssetEntryQuery
from com.liferay.portlet.asset.service import AssetEntryServiceUtil

aq = AssetEntryQuery()
aq.setAllCategoryIds([442492])
articles = AssetEntryServiceUtil.getEntries(aq)

for a in articles:
  out.write(str(a.title))
  out.write(str(a))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `className` in your AssetEntryQuery with the FQCN of the model you're looking for, eg. `assetEntryQuery.setClassName(BlogsEntry.class.getName());`

Comment: What if it's a content journal type I added e.g. challenges?

Comment: Then you have to set the `className` of your AssetEntryQuery to `JournalArticle.class.getName()`, and also do `assetEntryQuery.setClassTypeIds(new long[] {structureId});`, where `structureId` is the primary key of the JournalStructure you're looking for.